# I haven't got ntpd, is that going to cause issues in v16.04?

Tags: ntp

I have run

```
ntpd --version
```

and get output:

```
The program 'ntpd' can be found in the following packages:
* ntp
* openntpd
Try: sudo apt install <selected package>
```

I know this is for syncing time with another server. 
Mine is standalone pc and I don't aim to directly connect to another server, just go on internet.

Is this going to cause any problems? I've connected ok to the internet for now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default Ubuntu installs and uses [`systemd-timesyncd`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/en/man8/systemd-timesyncd.8.html), which provides automatic time synchronization with a (predefined or administrator-defined) NTP server; if you install `ntpd` (probably because you want to make the computer a NTP server) then `systemd-timesyncd` will be automatically disabled.

You should make sure that your computer has the correct time. To check that your computer is synchronized use the command

```
timedatectl
```

This will display the time synchronization status:

```
$ timedatectl
      Local time: Thu 2017-01-03 13:59:13 CET
  Universal time: Thu 2017-01-03 12:59:13 UTC
        RTC time: Thu 2017-01-03 12:59:14
       Time zone: Europe/Paris (CET, +0100)
 Network time on: yes
NTP synchronized: yes
 RTC in local TZ: no
```

Comment: Thanks, I have tried this and the time and timezone are correct, looks similar to above. So seems all good. Thanks for your fast response!

Comment: +1 for timedatectl, which I've never heard of.